# How to start back camera using webkitGetUserMedia

Tags: android, cordova, webkit, webrtc, mobile-webkit

I am trying to open a back video camera in old phone(android version 5.0). As these old device not supported `navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` so i am dependent only on webkitGetUserMedia. I have a success to open up a camera and show video but it is only using front camera and i need a back camera video. Here is my code

```
if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({video: true}, function(stream){
            video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        }, errBack);
```

I don't find any documentation related to this. Is there any way to open up back camera using webkitGetUserMedia? 
Secondly As i am using in cordova based application and by default Cordova use default system webview(Have option to use crosswalk but dont want to mix up it with cordova based app) is there any possibility to integrate any other webview to achieve this(getUserMedia etc) ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the facing mode

```
{ audio: true, video: { facingMode: "user" } }
```

or

```
{ audio: true, video: { facingMode: { exact: "environment" } } }
```

Comment: I already have tried these and it is not valid option for webkitGetUserMedia video. By adding these video stop showing on canvas

Answer (score 0):

First of all I highly recommend using the [AdapterJS](https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js) which shims all the differences through all the different browser implementations (good [blog](https://bloggeek.me/webrtc-adapter-js/) on this topic from Tsahi).

Secondly you are using the deprecated GUM-API, which I wouldn't recommend. I found an [issue](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/86) on a GitHub project which is exactly your issue, maybe this will help you.

Stated within the issue:

> The `navigator.getUserMedia` function is deprecated and you should instead use the newer `MediaDevices.getUserMedia` function. The [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) for the docs.

So if you applied these changes the GUM should accept the

`{ audio: true, video: { facingMode: { exact: "environment" } } }`

constraints (which the first answer stated correctly) which should give you the video stream of the back-camera of your phone.

Comment: Thanks for your detail response let me explain, As i mentioned in my post that i want to access camera in android device which are very old(Need to support a feature for these devices as well because they are in use by customer.) so these phones have old webview and i am stick with webkitGetUserMedia as webview have no idea about getUserMedia. As choosing a camera using getUserMedia is supper easy now a days but with webkitGetUserMedia it only allow to use front camera and have no idea how i can do change the setting to select back camera.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to take inspiration from how adapter.js shims facingMode in old versions:
https://github.com/webrtcHacks/adapter/blob/master/src/js/chrome/getusermedia.js

Basically it attempts to use navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices (you might have to resort to the earlier MediaStreamTrack.getSources() function) to enumerate devices and then attempts to guess which one is the back camera, passing the deviceId to getUserMedia. Be careful with this as your old version might have different constraint names (refer to the constraintsToChrome_ function) for the deviceId and documentation for this is very sparse.

Comment: Well this old phone webview even not support navigator.mediaDevices overall. As i said earlier only navigator.webkitGetUserMedia is available. Do you know from where i can find the documentation of webkitGetUserMedia?  i already google it but nothing found.

Comment: try MediaStreamTrack.getSources instead of enumerateDevices.

Comment: This is also not available.... Well thanks guys i found another solution through a cordova plugin which stream a camera to javascript and have ability to change the camera(front/back)..